# I have a button that when I press it increases a number to the number I want to save in local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that when I press it increases a number to the number I want to save in local storage
code

```
<div class="counter-btn counter-total counter-total-1" id="total" onclick="addnew();">0</div>
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("count");
    var count = (function (){
        var counter = 0;
        return function(){return counter += 1;}
    })();
    function addnew(){
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = count();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to increment a counter and keep track of its value with `localStorage`:

```js
const totalButton = document.getElementById('total');

// Doesn't work in StackOverflow:
// let currentValue = localStorage.getItem('count') || 0;

let currentValue = 0;

totalButton.innerHTML = currentValue;
    
totalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  totalButton.innerHTML = ++currentValue;
  
  // Doesn't work in StackOverflow:
  // localStorage.setItem('count', currentValue);
});
```

```css
#total {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: yellow;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#total:hover {
  background: olive;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="total" title="Click to increment">0</button>
```

Note the `localStorage` calls are commented out as they don't work in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addnew(){
    const newCount = count()
    localStorage.setItem("count", newCount);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = newCount;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.